# Simon game, player.delegate error: unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift

I am trying to make this Simon game app for practicing. As shown in the right code in the image attached, the author had 4 players for each color respectively and therefore, 4 delegates.

I tried to simplify it a little bit by using only one player, as shown in the left code. However, I got the error saying "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value". I don't understand why it would be optional as I unwrapped player using !.

What is the reason for the error?

Thanks.

[image: code comparison]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text – post the text.

Comment: You should instantiate the **player** object before assigning up the delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to a property of an object, while the object is nil and not yet initialized.

Move those lines of code

```
player.delegate = self
player.numberOfLoops = 0
```

to the playSound function

```
func playSound(soundName: String) {
   let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")
   player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
   player.delegate = self
   player.numberOfLoops = 0
   player.play()
}
```

Comment: but now the 'playSound()' function is doing a lot more than just the sound - better to call 'createPlayer()' and within that function create the player, assign delegate AND play sound

Comment: Nice! This works. Thanks Mo Al Waili!.  Just I don't understand why the position of player.delegate =self makes such a big difference?  Why can't it be put inside viewdidLoad() so the delegate is assigned at the very begining?

Comment: can I initialize player at the very beginning of the code using player=AVAudioPlayer()?